# checkbox postback in Mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, postback

What is a best usag **Razor** checkbox with postback?
for examle I have a class as follow

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public bool hi { get; set; }
}
```

and a view(with script):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#hi').change(function () {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
});
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Person</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SurName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SurName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SurName)
    </div>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.hi)

</fieldset>
}
```

I want postback when I click "hi" checkbox. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a bit jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#hi').change(function () {
      $(this).closest("form").submit();     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this out yet. But on the top of my mind, I would add a submit button within the Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post) curly braces, and add a style to it to display=none. In other words, it'l be hidden. Then I would add a checkbox event such as onValueChange using jquery (or maybe onClick maybe?, not sure of all of the events by heart.) Within the event block i'd simulate the button click by $('#btnInvisibleButton').Click(); Note that i had trouble executing .Clic() on Safari I think (there's a way around it by adding additional code specific to that browser , so you should test your code on all browsers.

Try this code, just make sure that the submit button is within the form tag:

```
$('#yourCheckBox').change(function () {
  $("#btnInvisibleButton").click();
});
```